# Integrating multiplication of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, integral

I have 2 matrices which I calculated separately.

One of the matrices is Y and its size is 2x25881 and the second one is U which is made out of 2 separate vectors like this:

```
U = [ArrayAT ; ArrayAD]
```

and the size of U is 2x25881.

Now, I want to calculate the integral of (my dt = 0.001):

[image]

The way I do it is:

```
 Y_Int_Sum = 0;

 for i = 1 : length(T)

     Y_Int_Sum = Y_Int_Sum + Y_Int(:,i)'*[ArrayAT(i) ; ArrayAD(i)]*dt;

 end
```

Is there any better way to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the element-wise multiplication of Y and U, then a sum over all the elements:

```
Y_Int_Sum = dt * sum(sum(Y_int .* [ArrayAT; ArrayAD]))
```